# codeigniter : pass data to a view included in a view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller and including two views from one function as below

```
$this->load->view('includes/header',$data);
$this->load->view('view_destinations',$data);
```

The view file `view_destinations.php` including a php menu file as follows

```
<? $this->load->view('includes/top_menu'); ?>
```

My question is, how can I pass data that is fetched from the controller to this included `top_menu.php` ?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Inside your controller, have

```
$data['nestedView']['otherData'] = 'testing';
```

before your view includes.

When you call

```
$this->load->view('view_destinations',$data);
```

the `view_destinations` file is going to have

```
$nestedView['otherData'];
```

Which you can at that point, pass into the nested view file.

```
<? $this->load->view('includes/top_menu', $nestedView); ?>
```

And inside your top_menu file you should have `$otherData` containing 'testing'.

Answer (score 6):

castis's solution works

however if you want to do this on a more finely grained level you can use:

```
//in your controller
$data['whatever'] = 'someValue';
```

.

```
//In your view
echo $whatever //outputs 'someValue';

//pass $whatever on
$this->load->view('some/view', Array('whatever' => $whatever));
```

Comment: I like this method best. I realised this was possible when I took a step back and thought about how CI handles variables passed from the Controller. Nice and clean.

Comment: This is very nice especially for the cases when you have 2+ level nested views and you can pass values directly from the view file rather than controller, like me :)

Answer (score 1):

This Codeigniter forum post should help you ;)

You can either make your $data (example) global in the controller, or pass just like @castis mentioned from within your view (variables only in your view)

More details here:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/88335/

Answer (score 1):

I have seen in my view files, if I'm passing data from controller to view and from that view to included nested view files. there is no need to transfer

> $data

for your nested view it is already available. you can directly access it, within your inner view.

Answer (score 1):

Also try this to if you want every single CodeIgniter view data in a subview:

```
echo $this->view('subview', get_defined_vars()['_ci_data']['_ci_vars'])
```