# How can I pass variable from a view to another view

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [codeigniter : pass data to a view included in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325633/codeigniter-pass-data-to-a-view-included-in-a-view)

How can I pass variable from a view to another view inside it?(codeigniter)

Thanks:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, that you set a variable in one view, then you call an other view inside that view and you would like to use it there, the easiest way, to set it in the controller, which call the view.

```
$data['var'] = 'value';
$this->load->view('view file',$data);
```

Then you can reach that in every sub view.